# htaccess URL Rewriting issue redirecting to localhost/c:/ on XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm building a new version of a PHP app that has over 180k news items stored in the Database. Many contain hardcoded links in the news.body to the old file structure, which points to something like this `people/7768-denis-grabe/` while the new file structure should be `single-player.php?id=7768`.

I'm really bad with REGEX and have very little understanding of how to work with .htaccess but I've been trying for two days to make a URL Rewrite rule which I think it's almost there but not quite yet.

In my .htaccess I have:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^people/([0-9]+)/?$ single-player.php?id=$1 [L]
```

It's not just rewriting the end of the URL, it's redirecting to the actual file, appending the `http://localhost:c/xampp/...` which gets me a 403 error forbidden page:

```
http://localhost/C:/xampp/htdocs/myapp/single-player.php?id=7768
```

All I need is to get the ID out of that first URL and rewrite it so it would redirect to the same address and just insert the ID as a GET request.

I'm working with XAMPP, `mod_rewrite` and `AllowOverride All` are already on

Thank you!

Comment: the old file structure looks a lot better, wouldent it be easier to keep using it?

Comment: It sure looks better, but the actual structure is really bad, that's why I'm making a new one. I might change how the URL looks in the near future, for now all I need is to make that work. But thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if maybe this works?

> RewriteRule ^people/([0-9]+).*$ single-player.php?id=$1 [L,NC]

Comment: Thank you, it works! What exactly was I doing wrong?
Actually now I have a new problem... It does load the desired page, not with the new URL but as @smith pointed out, that's actually good since the old format looks a lot better.
What's happening is that it loads the HTML but with no .css at all and in the console there's this error:
`bootstrap.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Comment: I think the issue was with your regex was that you have the `$` without a wildcard match - meaning that the extra data on the line after the match, i.e., `-denis-grabe/` was invalidating the match. I like to use [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) to test my regex's

Comment: That issue now sound like it's probably just a syntax error somewhere in your code.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that when I visit the URL like `/single-player.php?id=7768` I get a perfect page and that error just happens on `people/7768-denis-grabe/`

Comment: Maybe you are referencing stylesheets / resources relative to page root, which is now change one directory level? Use your browsers 'inspect'; function to check for resources that have failed to load.